# Using the Azure AppFabric Cache in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: caching, azure, azure-appfabric, asp.net-mvc

I have configured the Azure AppFabric Cache as session provider in my ASP.NET MVC application.

How do i store session data in Azure Cache?

Is it the same was as with inProc session?
Like by using ViewBag, TempData and stuff?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you configured AppFabric as session provider you can now use Session State just in the same way when you had InProc session. Other features that use Session State (for example TempData) also work.

Comment: is there a way to view the cache contents?

Comment: That's not my experience. Session works, but not in the same way! See my session variable question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414014/session-variable-not-updating-when-using-azure-cache

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't already, I'd encourage you to have a look at this section in the Windows Azure Training Kit.  It does a very good job of demonstrating how to use Windows Azure Caching.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_buildingappswithcacheservice#_Toc310505077